# How do I represent $ARCH-pc-linux-gnu in a Debian install file?

Tags: ppa, packaging

I am presently working on a [GNU Octave PPA](https://launchpad.net/~brentonhorne/+archive/ubuntu/octave). My `octave.install` file (which to my knowledge follows the same formatting conventions of rules files) needs to include files from:

```
usr/lib/${DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH}/octave/${DEB_VERSION_UPSTREAM}/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/*
```

for the 64-bit (or amd64) build and:

```
usr/lib/${DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH}/octave/${DEB_VERSION_UPSTREAM}/exec/i386-pc-linux-gnu/*
```

for the 32-bit build. How do I write my install file so that it will include these files on these respective systems? I have tried:

```
ARCH=$(uname -m)
usr/lib/${DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH}/octave/${DEB_VERSION_UPSTREAM}/exec/$ARCH-pc-linux-gnu/*
```

in the hope that the similarities between rules files and shell script, in terms of their syntax, would allow this line to work. But the `$ARCH` variable was left unevaluated (i.e., it was left as `$ARCH`, and not substituted for the value I defined in the line before) and the build failed ([here](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/293837659/buildlog_ubuntu-xenial-amd64.octave_4.2.0-1ubuntu0~xenial8_BUILDING.txt.gz) is the build log).

**EDIT**: Launchpad just finished attempting to build the suggestion to use `${ARCH}` instead of `$ARCH` in the aforementioned attempted fix. Here is the error:

```
find debian/tmp -name '*.la' -delete
make[1]: Leaving directory `/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>'
   dh_install -a -O--parallel
    install -d debian/octave//usr/bin
    cp -a debian/tmp/usr/bin/octave-4.2.0 debian/octave//usr/bin/
    cp -a debian/tmp/usr/bin/octave-cli debian/octave//usr/bin/
    cp -a debian/tmp/usr/bin/octave-cli-4.2.0 debian/octave//usr/bin/
    cp -a debian/tmp/usr/share/applications debian/octave//usr/share/
    install -d debian/octave/-m\)
    cp -a debian/tmp/ARCH=\$\(uname debian/octave/-m\)/
cp: cannot stat ‘debian/tmp/ARCH=$(uname’: No such file or directory
dh_install: cp -a debian/tmp/ARCH=$(uname debian/octave/-m)/ returned exit code 1
make: *** [binary-arch] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary-arch gave error exit status 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Build finished at 20161117-1936
```

Comment: Did you try `${ARCH}`?

Comment: No, are you sure it will work? I ask because everytime I try this it takes up up 30MB of my upload bandwidth as I have to re-upload my orig.tar.gz file too.

Comment: No I am not sure it will work, but I am fairly confident. Reading the manual now. Why aren't you building locally before the upload?

Comment: I suspect the solution @Seth proposed with work. If the install file follows the same convention as the rules file, and the rules file is a Makefile (according to [this](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/debian-dir-overview.html) page), it follows that, according to the [make manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html), "To substitute a variable's value, write a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable in parentheses or braces"

Comment: From everything I can find in the manual it should work, assuming the parameter gets properly set, which I am not sure you can do from an install file.

Comment: I'll give it a try (my previous comment I deleted because I found that I didn't include braces). I'll know if it worked in about an hour or more.

Comment: Build just failed, I included the error in the question.

Comment: Would `usr/lib/${DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH}/octave/${DEB_VERSION_UPSTREAM}/exec/${DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH/-linux/-pc-linux}`  work?

Comment: @Seth ping, any ideas?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48675/discussion-on-question-by-brenton-horne-how-do-i-represent-arch-pc-linux-gnu-in).

Comment: Try 'uname -m' possibly with back ticks... Just a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like `${DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH}`, there are other variables for architecture information details. As documented below from Debian policy manual:

> ### 4.9 Main building script: `debian/rules`
>
> The architectures we build on and build for are determined by `make` variables using the utility `dpkg-architecture`. You can determine the Debian architecture and the GNU style architecture specification string for the build architecture as well as for the host architecture. The build architecture is the architecture on which `debian/rules` is run and the package build is performed. The host architecture is the architecture on which the resulting package will be installed and run. These are normally the same, but may be different in the case of cross-compilation (building packages for one architecture on machines of a different architecture).
>
> Here is a list of supported make variables:
>
> ```
> DEB_*_ARCH (the Debian architecture)    
> DEB_*_ARCH_CPU (the Debian CPU name)
> DEB_*_ARCH_OS (the Debian System name)
> DEB_*_GNU_TYPE (the GNU style architecture specification string)
> DEB_*_GNU_CPU (the CPU part of DEB_*_GNU_TYPE)
> DEB_*_GNU_SYSTEM (the System part of DEB_*_GNU_TYPE)
> ```
>
> where `*` is either `BUILD` for specification of the build architecture or `HOST` for specification of the host architecture.
>
> Backward compatibility can be provided in the rules file by setting the needed variables to suitable default values; please refer to the documentation of `dpkg-architecture` for details.
>
> It is important to understand that the `DEB_*_ARCH` string only determines which Debian architecture we are building on or for. It should not be used to get the CPU or system information; the `DEB_*_ARCH_CPU` and `DEB_*_ARCH_OS` variables should be used for that. GNU style variables should generally only be used with upstream build systems.
>
> <sub>**Source:** https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html</sub>

The one you are looking for is `DEB_HOST_GNU_CPU`. So the new install line should be:

```
usr/lib/${DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH}/octave/${DEB_VERSION_UPSTREAM}/exec/${DEB_HOST_GNU_CPU}-pc-linux-gnu/*
```

You can have a look on values of these variables in your local machine by running:

```
~$ dpkg-architecture
DEB_BUILD_ARCH=amd64
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_BITS=64
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_CPU=amd64
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_ENDIAN=little
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_OS=linux
DEB_BUILD_GNU_CPU=x86_64
DEB_BUILD_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnu
DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE=x86_64-linux-gnu
DEB_BUILD_MULTIARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu
DEB_HOST_ARCH=amd64
DEB_HOST_ARCH_BITS=64
DEB_HOST_ARCH_CPU=amd64
DEB_HOST_ARCH_ENDIAN=little
DEB_HOST_ARCH_OS=linux
DEB_HOST_GNU_CPU=x86_64
DEB_HOST_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnu
DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE=x86_64-linux-gnu
DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu
DEB_TARGET_ARCH=amd64
DEB_TARGET_ARCH_BITS=64
DEB_TARGET_ARCH_CPU=amd64
```